# $A \subset S$ and $B \subset S$ are negatively correlated

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Let $s_1,...,s_m$ be i.i.d (independent and identically distributed) random variables, distributed on the set
{1,2, ..., n}
and consider the (random) set
$S = \{s_1, ..., s_m\}$.

For any given disjoint subsets
$A,B \subset {1,..., n}$
Prove that
$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B \subset S) ≤ \mathbb{P}(A \subset S)\mathbb{P}(B \subset S)$
that is, the events ${A \subset S}$ and ${B \subset S}$ are negatively correlated.

This looks like Harris's inequality (or the more general FKG inequality), but I couldn't find a way to apply it.

We may assume
$A = \{1,2,...,|A|\}, B = \{n-|B|+1, ..., n\}$
as they are disjoint.
Now, I tried applying the FKG to the lattice
$\{1,...,n\}^m$
with usual lexicographical order, but it doesn't seem to work since the event
${A \subset S}$
is not monotonic.

Do you have a suggestion, or perhaps a hint or a solution?

I attached a link to the FKG inequality from Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not convinced that the FKG inequality would apply here, as usually it is applied to deduce positive correlations. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, I would suspect that one has to use the [BK inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_den_Berg%E2%80%93Kesten_inequality) instead.

Comment: I've actually considered it, but got stuck quite quickly because I don't think those events (or similar events) could be determined by two disjoint sets of the $s_i-s$. I thought FKG/Harris had better chance as we might be able to construct suitable increasing function and decreasing function (and construct a suitable lattice) and apply FKG.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the event $\{A \cup B \subset S\}$ is a priori the disjoint occurence of $\{A \subset S\}$ and $\{B \subset S\}$ by virtue of the fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Remember that sets of indices you have to check for the conditions of disjoint occurence are allowed to depend on the configuration itself (this is a point which is, in my opinion, not made clear in the Wikipedia article). But the indices of the $s_i \in S$ which make up $A$ and the indices of the $s_j \in S$ which make up $B$ must necessarily be disjoint, since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing so sophisticated as FKG or BK is required. You can give a direct <strike>combinatorial</strike> probabilistic proof.

Let $t_1,\dots,t_m$ be random variables which are distributed identically to $s_1,\dots, s_m$, such that all $2m$ of these random variables are independent.

Let $E$ be the event that $A\cup B\subseteq \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$, so $P(E)=P(S\subseteq A\cup B)$.

Let $F$ be the event that $A\subseteq \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$ and $B\subseteq \{t_1,\dots,t_m\}$. Note $P(F)=P(S\subseteq A)\cdot P(S\subseteq B)$.

Your claim is equivalent to $P(E)\le P(F)$. To prove this, I will define a function $\Phi$, where the input to $\Phi$ is an outcome in $E$, and the output of $\Phi$ is an outcome in $F$. The function $\Phi$ will be probability-preserving, in the sense that for any outcome $\omega$, we have $P(\{\omega\})=P(\{\Phi(\omega)\})$. Therefore, the existence of $\Phi$ will prove that $P(E)\le P(F)$.

The map $\Phi$ is defined as follows. We are given a random vector
$$
(s_1,\dots,s_m,t_1,\dots,t_m),
$$
such that $A\cup B\subseteq \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$. The goal is to produce a new list
$$
(s_1',\dots,s_m',t_1',\dots,t_m')
$$
such that $A\subseteq \{s_1',\dots,s_m'\}$, and $B\subseteq \{t_1',\dots,t_m'\}$. We do this according to the following simple rule. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,m\},$
$$
(s_i',t_i')=\begin{cases}
(s_i,t_i) & \text{if $s_i\in A$}
\\
(t_i,s_i) & \text{if $s_i\notin A$}
\end{cases}
$$
In words, for each $i$, we look to see if $s_i\in A$, and if it is not, then we switch $s_i$ with $t_i$. Since $s_1,\dots,s_m$ originally covered $A$, and we did not remove any instances of $A$, the new $(s_1',\dots,s_m')$ still covers $A$. Since $s_1,\dots,s_m$ covers $B$, and we moved all instances of $B$ over to $t_1',\dots,t_m'$, the output list $t_1',\dots,t_m'$ will cover $B$. Therefore, the output is an outcome in $F$. Furthermore, since $\Phi$ only rearranges some entries of a list of i.i.d. variables, $\Phi$ is probability-preserving. This completes the proof.

Comment: Does this method generalise to the case where the $s_i$ are not distributed uniformly on $\{ 1, \dots, n\}$? This is not an assumption made in the original post.

Comment: @Julius My answer should be completely correct now.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!!